# Array product given a dynamic number of arguments

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I have a function that does an array product:

```
arrayProduct(l1,l2,l3) = [[a, b, c] |
    a := l1[_]
    b := l2[_]
    c := l3[_]
]
```

If I have three arrays defined as follows:

```
animals1 = ["hippo", "giraffe"]
animals2 = ["lion", "zebra"]
animals3 = ["deer", "bear"]
```

Then the output of `arrayProduct(animals1, animals2, animals3)` would be:

```
[["hippo","lion","deer"],["hippo","lion","bear"],["hippo","zebra","deer"],["hippo","zebra","bear"],["giraffe","lion","deer"],["giraffe","lion","bear"],["giraffe","zebra","deer"],["giraffe","zebra","bear"]]
```

If I can guarantee that the inputs will always be lists is there away I could make a function that would do the same thing except it could accept a dynamic number of lists as input instead of just 3?

I'm also exploring if it would also be possible to do this with only one argument containing all the arrays within it as opposed to accepting multiple arguments. For example:

```
[["hippo", "giraffe"], ["lion", "zebra"], ["deer", "bear"], ["ostrich", "flamingo"]]
```

Any insight into a solution with either approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's no known way to compute an arbitrary N-way cross product in Rego without a builtin.

Why something can't be written in a language can be tricky to explain because it amounts to a proof-sketch.  We need to make the argument that there is no policy in Rego that computes an N-way cross product.  The formal proofs of expressiveness/complexity have not been worked out, so the best we can do is try  to articulate why it might not be possible.

For the N-way cross product, it boils down to the fact that Rego guarantees termination for all policies on all inputs, and to do that it restricts how deeply nested iteration can be. In your example (using `some` and indentation for clarity) you have 3 nested loops with indexes `i`, `j`, `k`.

```
arrayProduct(l1,l2,l3) = [[a, b, c] |
    some i
        a := l1[i]
        some j
            b := l2[j]
            some k
                c := l3[k]
]
```

To implement an N-way cross product `arrayProduct([l1, l2, ..., ln])` you would need something equivalent to N nested loops:

```
# NOT valid Rego
arrayProduct([l1,l2,...,ln]) = [[a, b, ..., n] |
    some i1
        a := l1[i1]
        some i2
            b := l2[i2]
              ...
                    n := ln[in]
]
```

where importantly the degree of nested iteration N depends on the input.

To guarantee termination, Rego restricts the degree of nested iteration in a policy.  You can only nest iteration as many times as you have `some` (or more properly variables) appearing in your policy.  This is analogous to SQL restricting the number of JOINs to those that appear in the query and view definitions.

Since the degree of nesting required for an N-way cross product is N, and N can be larger than the number of `some`s in the policy, there is no way to implement the N-way cross product.

As a point of contrast, the number of keys or values that are iterated over inside any one loop CAN and usually DO depend on the input.  It's the number of loops that cannot depend on the input.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to compute an n-ary product of lists/arrays (or sets or objects) in Rego without adding a built-in function.

In the scenario described above, providing a dynamic number of arrays as input to the function would be equivalent to passing an array of arrays (like you mentioned at the end):

```
arrayProduct([arr1, arr2, ..., arrN])
```

This works, except that when we try to implement `arrayProduct` we get stuck because Rego does not permit recursion and iteration only occurs when you inject a variable into a reference. In your original example `l1[_]` is a reference to the elements in the first list and `_` is a unique variable referring to the array indices in that list.

OPA/Rego evaluates that expression by finding assignments to each `_` that satisfy the query. The "problem" is that this requires one variable for each list in the input. If the length of the array of arrays is unknown, we would need an infinite number of variables.

If you really need an n-ary product function I would suggest you implement a [custom built-in function](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/extensions/) for now.